# how to read the weight of each feature from trainning lstm cell

Tags: tensorflow

I used several time series as features (3 features as input) into LSTM model (1 output on regression) on TF 1.1.0. The main function started a session as below:

```
model = SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model, 
              model_dir=LOG_DIR,
              params={'learning_rate': Learning_rate}))
model.fit(trainX, trainY, steps=steps)
```

and the lstm_model function as below mainly:

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.1)
(output, state) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

After training and saving the model (saved automatically by the default tf function itself), I could read the weights of the LSTM cell by 'import_meta_graph' and 'restore' in the main function. The weights looks like a (131, 512) array.

The problem is how to know the weights of each feature from such a weights array, i.e. each feature's weights to the output?

BTW, if you use the default tf function, could I save the customized model when trainning? How to do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Explain: If I add one more feature to the input, the weights will be (132,512) array.

Comment: the batch_size =1

Answer (score 0):

I think weights[131, 512] could be explain like this:

Because of 128 hidden layers, 3 features

1. D-131 variables are the weights of the 3 features, 128 hidden layers(still not sure).
2. D-512 variables are the weights of the input gate, forget gate, cell state, and output gate in each hidden layers, 4*128 = 512.
   Am I right?